# AOP. Hibernate EventListeners

Tags: spring, hibernate, aop

I am trying to use Hibernate event listeners with AOP. My code:

```java
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraints(columnNames = "code", name = "uc_some_table_code")
public class MyEntity {
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}
```

```java
public class MyEntityListener {
    @AnnotationForAudit(name = "EVENT1")
    @PostPersist
    private postCreate(MyEntity myEntity) {}
    
    @AnnotationForAudit(name= "EVENT2")
    @PreUpdate
    private void preUpdate(MyEntity myEntity) {}
}
```

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AnnotationForAudit {
  String name() default "";
}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService {
    private final MyEntityRepository repository;
    private final MyEntityMapper mapper;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public MyEntity create(MyEntityModel model) {
        var entity = mapper.fromModel(model);
        return mapper.toModel(repository.save(entity));
    }
}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuditEventAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(annotationForAudit)")
    public void callAnnotatedmethod(AnnotationForAudit annotation) {}
    
    @before(value = "callAnnotatedmethod(annotation)", argnames="joinPoint,annotation")
    public void beforeCallAnnotatedmethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, AnnotationForAudit annotation) {
         System.out.println("do something...");
    }
}
```

I want to intercept the Hibernate event when saving or editing an entity, but this configuration does not work. I explicitly declared the listener as a bean in application configuration - and no, it does not work anyway. But if I inject it into the service and call it methods, then the aspect works.

Answer (score 0):

**Background:** Spring AOP is based on JDK dynamic proxies for interfaces or CGLIB proxies for class types. Proxies rely on sub-classing, and in Java subclasses or other classes other than the declaring class do not have access to private methods. Therefore, you also cannot intercept private methods using proxy-based AOP technologies.

**Solution:** Make your listener method public, then it works.

**Alternative:** If your really need to intercept private methods, you have to switch to a more powerful AOP technology like AspectJ. AspectJ does not work proxy-based, so there you can intercept private methods.